# How to find which downscaling algorithm used?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, downsampling

I have a very specific problem. I have 2 image sets of the same photos watermarked. One image dataset is 1280x960 resolution. The second dataset is the 640x480 resolution. I am trying to find which downsampling algorithm being used to downscale 1280x960 to 640x480 images. Is there anyone who has some example code for it? or any guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most common method for downsampling is ndimage.interpolation.zoom. It uses bicubic splines internally. 
Something like:

```
from scipy import ndimage
low_resolution_frame = ndimage.interpolation.zoom(frame, 0.5)
```